# react form submits every time state changes

Tags: reactjs, forms

So I've got a form which sends formData to api, goes like this:

```
const [state, setState] = useState(true)

const handleSubmit = async e => {
  const destination = state ? true : false
  // Sends FormData to api
}

return (
  <form onSumbit={handleSubmit}>
    <div>
      <button onClick={() => setState(prev => !prev)}>click</button
      <button onClick={() => setState(prev => !prev)}>click</button
    </div>

    // some more inputs here

    <input type="submit" value="Upload" />
  </form>
```

Every time state changes it tries to submit again. It does that only for the state used in submitHandler to calculate destination. I also tried moving destination outside of submitHandler but the result is the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add `type="button"` on your prev/next buttons:
https://playcode.io/1495308

```html
<button type="button" onClick={() => setState(prev => !prev)}>click</button>
```

html forms assume that buttons are submit buttons by default:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/submit#additional_attributes

Answer (score 0):

The problem you're encountering, where the form tries to submit again every time the state changes, is likely due to the re-rendering behavior of **React**. Since the state update triggers **re-render**, the form `onSubmit` event is being registered again and causing another submission attempt.

To prevent this behavior, you can make a small adjustment to your code by add type="button" to you button element.
[How to prevent buttons from submitting forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/932653/how-to-prevent-buttons-from-submitting-forms)